# Automate firewall rule verification

Tags: powershell, telnet, firewall, powershell-remoting

In order to verify a newly implemented firewall rule, I typically do the following manually:

Ex. Firewall rule: SRC-ip, DST-ip, DST-port, (protocol=TCP)

1. Login to the SRC box
2. Open up a cmd window on the SRC box (assuming Windows OS)
3. telnet   (and check for connectivity)

   - I would like to automate this (to verify a long list of rules) using batch-scripting or PowerShell scripting.
   - I would like to be able to run the script on a **third** machine (other than SRC/DST).

I tried to use "Enter-PSSession" on PowerShell window to fire off remote telnet command but it didn't work, the telnet command just returned nothing.

Please share any ideas on how to implement this script.

Thanks,

Jatin

Comment: Windows build-in telnet client does not use standard input and output streams, so it is not fit for automation. You need to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

check this one: http://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/04/04/using-powershell-as-a-telnet-client/ which based on Lee-Holmes code:

http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/08/30/replacing-telnet-exe-now-removed-from-vista/

Also you can add your commands to a text file and execute it using plink.exe(Putty Link) with the `-m` switch

```
-m file   read remote command(s) from file
```

Comment: Thanks PetSerAl and Avshalom. Now I think I will be better off writing java code instead of hankering over telnet with powershell.